# Adding external class folder to the build path in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath, .class-file

I have an external .class file. I added this through:

Right Click to project>BuildPath>Configure Build Path>Libraries>Add External Class Folder

This is my folder structure. I am supposed to create an instance of SOS class. But I got errors in compilation. Where is the problem ?

[image]

My SOS.class file is located in desktop, inside Classes folder

Answer (score 0):

Give a package name for SSO class.Compile that and then add it in reference library.

In Test.java write

> import your.packge.name.SSO;

avoid using default packages when you want to import classes from them.

Comment: I can't see refactor option for default package :( how will i give it a name

Comment: Test is in the default package, so it should be able to reference SOS. It's only if you want to import the class from a class in a non default package that you get issues.